# Connection Between Uniform Continuity and Uniform Convergence?

Tags: real-analysis

The problem I have posed to me is given below:

"Let E be a non-empty subset of $\Bbb{R}$. Let $f_n: E \to \Bbb{R}$ be functions on E with n\in{\Bbb{N}} such that each function $f_n$ is bounded, that is, $\Vert{f_n}\Vert_u \lt \infty$. Suppose $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on E.

1) Prove $f$ is bounded on E

2) Prove there exists M such that $\Vert f_n \Vert_u \le$ M for all n $\in{\Bbb{N}}$

I honestly have no idea how to even approach this! Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You  should change the title -  this has nothing to do  with continuity..

Answer (score 1):

1. Pick some $\epsilon$ (say, $\epsilon = 1$). By the definition of uniform convergence, you can find some $n$ such that $\sup_{x \in E} |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. So, $f$ is close to $f_n$ everywhere on $E$, and you already know $f_n$ is bounded. Can you fill in the details?
2. Pick some $\epsilon$ (say, $\epsilon = 1$). By the definition of uniform convergence, there is some $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $\sup_{x \in E} |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. By the previous part, you already know $f$ is bounded, so this provides you with a bound $M$ for $\|f_n\|_u$ for all $n \ge N$. It remains to consider $\|f_n\|_u$ for $n < N$, but there are finitely many of these, so you can just take the maximum of $M$ with these finitely many values.